# Как сделать дополнительное окно в игре?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

В основном игровом окне, нужно сделать дополнительное окно с другой "игрой"! Например, в основной игре, персонаж нажимает на кнопку, должно появиться окно в которому нужно решить простенькую головоломку, или набрать комбинацию из кнопок, или еще чего-нибудь!

Собственно вопрос как это лучше сделать?

- **GUI**: Это ресурсоемко, и ограничивает возможности! Подойдет для "тыканья по кнопкам", но не подойдет для головоломки с физикой (А это нужно тоже, и без этого никак!=( )
- **Загружать в отдельной сцене**: Не знаю как вернуть сцену в первоначальный вид(как до нажатия кнопки) что бы все враги и изменения остались на месте, да и к тому же это не рационально для маленьких "мини-игры", и если основная сцена большая, то она будет долго грузиться после выхода из "мини-игры"
- **С помощью 3d объектов**: Это только идея, вообще еще не знаю как реализовать! (Есть возможность "отвернуть" камеру от основный игры, так как она 2D)

Может быть можно также скомбинировать это методы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто отобразить поверх вашей основной трёхмерной сцены несколько двумерных полигонов. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Хм, а эти полигоны можно собрать и разместить в нужно мести в редакторе, и просто держать не активными, а в нужны момент активировать)!